# Add [packer] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[Packer](https://www.packer.io/) is a tool which automates building and provisioning of VM and Docker images.

Questions that would use the [packer](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/packer) tag:

- [Deploy packer images on bare metal server?](https://serverfault.com/q/625377/219235)
- [Chef installation in a chroot (packer): not starting services](https://serverfault.com/q/641086/219235)
- [How do I set locale when building an Ubuntu Docker image with Packer?](https://serverfault.com/q/636990/219235)
- [No builder returned for name: vagrant Packer.io error](https://serverfault.com/q/538914/219235)
- [How to configure ssh access for an unattended linux-distro ISO image for local development env similar to accessing cloud service VM instances?](https://serverfault.com/q/646244/219235)
- [How to use terraform.io to change the image of a stateful server without downtime or data loss?](https://serverfault.com/q/616778/219235)
- [cloud-init does not grow the partition nor the filesystem](https://serverfault.com/q/622707/219235)

Comment: I added the tag to http://serverfault.com/questions/616778/how-to-use-terraform-io-to-change-the-image-of-a-stateful-server-without-downtim

Comment: ...and within a few seconds, I added it to a different question.  Please go ahead and provide a tag summary and/or description for this tag, and feel free to edit (well, suggest edits, in your case) the tag into questions where it's appropriate.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sven thanks for creating the tag!

Comment: @HopelessN00b tag summary proposed; tagged several questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag has been created and this is an answer just so the question can be considered answered.

Comment: I was hoping @Sven would post the answer so that I could accept it, but this will do.

Comment: Needs an upvote to be considered answered